# (Theoreticaly) Fast performing Routine for tensor manipulation going slower than not optimized version

Tags: python, numpy, performance, tensor

The goal of this implementation is to manipulate a 4 dimensional tensor in order to contact it with himself and then truncate the inflated indexes back to their original length.

I have two routines that differ in the following point:

- **Routine One** memory complexity scales with the dimension of the tensor to the power of 5, since the `tensorB2` and `tensorC`, which have shape `(dimension,dimension,dimesion,dimension,dimension)` have to be computed.
  for `dimension = 60` this takes about *66s*.
- **Routine Two** computes exactly the same thing, but the computations of `tensorB2` and `tensorC` have been split in order to never compute a tensor that is bigger than `(dimension,dimension,dimesion,dimension)` thus scaling with dimension^4, but takes about *30min*.

Again I want to underline that **This routines compute exactly the same result**, and, in the theory, routine 2 computational complexity should be even better than the one of routine 1.

**I want to optimize Routine2**

My guess is that I am using numpy`s ndarrays wrong, therefore repeating useless operation like copying Tensors in memory when not need.

**Imports and functions**

```py
import numpy as np 
from ncon import ncon
def truncate_matrix(matrix,index,dim):
    shape=list(matrix.shape)
    shape[index]=dim
    newMatrix= matrix[0:shape[0],0:shape[1]]
    return newMatrix
```

**Routine 1** (memory scaling dimension^5)

```py
dimension = 60 
myTensor  = np.random.rand(dimension,dimension,dimension,dimension)
tensorA = ncon([myTensor,myTensor],[[-1,1,2,-3],[-2,1,2,-4]])
tensorB = ncon([myTensor,myTensor],[[-1,1,-3,2],[-2,1,-4,2]])
tensorQ = ncon([tensorA,tensorB],[[-1,-3,1,2],[-2,-4,1,2]])
del tensorA,tensorB
#Finding Utr 
Qshape =  tensorQ.shape
tensorQ = tensorQ.reshape((Qshape[0]*Qshape[1],Qshape[2]*Qshape[3]))
Ul, deltaL, _ = np.linalg.svd(tensorQ)
Utr = np.array(truncate_matrix(Ul, 1, dimension))
Utr = Utr.reshape((Qshape[0],Qshape[1],dimension))
del tensorQ,Ul,Qshape
#Recontructing T 
tensorB2 = ncon([Utr,myTensor],[[1,-5,-1],[1,-4,-2,-3]])
tensorC  = ncon([tensorB2,myTensor],[[-1,-2,1,-4,2],[2,-5,1,-3]])
del tensorB2
newTensor1 = ncon([Utr,tensorC],[[1,2,-2],[-1,-3,-4,1,2]])          
del tensorC
```

**Routine 2** (memory scaling dimension^4)

```py
dimension = 60 
myTensor  = np.random.rand(dimension,dimension,dimension,dimension)
tensorA = ncon([myTensor,myTensor],[[-1,1,2,-3],[-2,1,2,-4]])
tensorB = ncon([myTensor,myTensor],[[-1,1,-3,2],[-2,1,-4,2]])
tensorQ = ncon([tensorA,tensorB],[[-1,-3,1,2],[-2,-4,1,2]])
#Finding Utr 
Qshape =  tensorQ.shape
tensorQ = tensorQ.reshape((Qshape[0]*Qshape[1],Qshape[2]*Qshape[3]))
Ul, deltaL, _ = np.linalg.svd(tensorQ)
Utr = np.array(truncate_matrix(Ul, 1, dimension))
Utr = Utr.reshape((Qshape[0],Qshape[1],dimension))
courrentShape = myTensor.shape
newTensor2 = np.zeros((dimension,dimension,courrentShape[2],courrentShape[3]))
#Recontructing T 
for xf in range(0,newTensor2.shape[0]):
    for yu in range(0,dimension):
        #Slice courrent tensor
        tensorSlice = myTensor[:,:,yu,:] # T_iy1y'1
        # Slice truncation matrix
        matrixSlice = Utr[:,:,xf] # Uy1y2
        tensorB2 = ncon([matrixSlice,tensorSlice],[[1,-3],[1,-2,-1]]) 
        for yb in range(0,newTensor2.shape[3]):
            tensorSlice =  myTensor[:,:,:,yb]
            tensorC = ncon([tensorB2,tensorSlice],[[1,-1,2],[2,-2,1]])
            newTensor2[xf,:,yu,yb] = ncon([Utr,tensorC],[[1,2,-1],[1,2]])
```

Comment: I haven't seen `ncon` before, but from the docs examples it looks like a generalized `np,dot` or `np.einsum`.  But I don't know how well it works or scales. You code is too complex to apply intuitions from other cases.  While you start with (60,60,60,60) shaped arrays, I can't tell from a simple read how the array shapes evolve.

Comment: Nested iteration like this doesn't reduce the overall complexity.  It may simplify in the inner most action, but if you have to do that 60^3 times, you aren't going to save time.  A few iterations (e.g. 60) on a complex operation can save time when the arrays are very large, since memory management for larger arrays becomes time consuming.  But you appear to be doing a lot of iterations.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are optimizing for memory usage but want to achieve better/same cpu performance? At some point, when memory usage is very high it may help or be the only way to do it, but for your case (N=60) it should not be a problem on modern computers.

Comment: The point is that iI want to crank up N to >100 , the mmeory optimization is now working and scales up to 100 but is very slow, and operation takes up to 20 min and in my implementation I have to run up to 100 computations. I managed to get better performance by reordering some operations, I will update and simplify the code